# iOS9 UILocalNotification soundName not work

Tags: ios

I have an app which is about local notification. When I schedule a local notification, and it will work. However, after the local notification is closed, then I schedule a local notification immediately by using "NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:" After that, I make my phone to be locked, then the local notification still work, but there is no soundName!! After searching Google for a period, I still can't find the reason... Anyone can help me solve the problem? By the way, the first local notification's soundName is work.

Answer (score 1):

First, please ensure that following property is set in Capabilities tap of your target:

[image]

If this is set correctly then try setting audio session properties:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error: nil];
UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:nil];
[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
```

Comment: AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute error:nil];
[session setActive:YES error:nil];        These three lines are what I use in my project. I don't set background modes in iOS8.4, and it can work properly. However in iOS9, it can't not work. The detail situation is when I  make my app into backgroud for a while, the screen will become dark slowly, then being locked. After that, even the local notification comes, there is only notification, but no sound...

Comment: @DavidWu Hi, i have the same issue here did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason is that you can only use audio file less than 30 second. Make sure that you didn't use a audio larger than 30 second.